# Android how to get values from columns in a sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a sqlite table called **TermTable** with the columns *id*, *term* and *type*:

```
static final String TermTable = "Terms";
static final String ID = "id";
static final String Term = "term";
static final String Type = "type";
```

Also, I have a Datasource class that implements the db and have the following methods to put and get data in and out of table:

```
public long insertTermList(String term, String type) {

    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();

    initialValues.put(WordsDB.Term, term);
    initialValues.put(WordsDB.Type, type);

    return db.insert(WordsDB.TermTable, null, initialValues);
}

public Cursor getTermValues(int index) {

    String from[] = { "Term", "Type" };
    String where = WordsDB.ID + "=" + index;
    Cursor cursor = db.query(true, WordsDB.TermTable, from, where, null, null, null, null, null);
    return cursor;
}
```

In another class I have invoked the insertTermList and inserted some for rows of values using a Datasource object called **ds**:

```
private void setData()
{
    ds.insertTermList("abbey", "noun");
    ds.insertTermList("abide", "verb");
    ds.insertTermList("abound", "verb");
    ds.insertTermList("absurd", "adjective");
}
```

Now I want to get values from the columns according to the id I give it and append each column value of each row to a text view called **text**. How can I do that?

```
private void getData() {

    Cursor c = ???

    if(c != null)
    {
        c.moveToFirst();
        text.append(???);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So,
first of all, change your following function:

```
public Cursor getTermValues(int index) {

    String from[] = { "Term", "Type" };
    String where = WordsDB.ID + "=" + index;
    Cursor cursor = db.query(true, WordsDB.TermTable, from, where, null, null, null, null, null);
    return cursor;
}
```

to

```
public Cursor getTermValues(int index) {

    String from[] = { "Term", "Type" };
    String where = WordsDB.ID + "=?";
    String[] whereArgs = new String[]{index+""};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(WordsDB.TermTable, from, where, whereArgs, null, null, null, null);
    return cursor;
}
```

then,

```
    private void getData(int id) {

        Cursor c = getTermValues(id);

        if(c != null)
        {
            while(c.moveToNext){
                String term = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("term")));
                String type = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("type")));


                // use these strings as you want
            }
        }
    }
```

if you want to ge all the records then create a method:

```
public void getAllRecords() {

    Cursor cursor = db.query(WordsDB.TermTable, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    if(c != null)
            {
                while(c.moveToNext){
                    String term = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("term")));
                    String type = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("type")));


                    // use these strings as you want
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: So, what is the range of ids I can feed for getData method? I tried 0 and nothing was printed and tried 1 and I got IllegalStateException get field slot from row 0 col -1 faild.

Comment: Do you want to display all the records ?

Comment: yes, all the column values of each row I inserted. you know how?

Comment: Still get IllegalStateException get field slot from row 0 col -1 faild. Have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Please post your full activity code and logcat errors, i think your database is not open while you are querying database.

Comment: I got it. the code c.getColumnIndex("term") must change to c.getColumnIndex("Term") and for type as well. The column names didn't match.

Comment: Yeah. I too found this in your question. I was confused because you defined constants, so i thought it might be the column names.

Comment: You know when I print c.getString(...) only the word absurd shows up and 9 times.